# Set date in database MYSQL php to Zero

Tags: php, mysql, date

How can i set the date in php to : 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

So I can update the database to date equal to "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the date field to null in sql

```
UPDATE  tableName SET dateField = NULL WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 1):

While creating database filed, its **TYPE** should be **DATETIME**. So when record will be inserted with blank date value, it will be saved 0000-00-00 00:00:00 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` datatype.By default it will take `0000-00-00 00:00:00`